# Add color with extendtraces

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I know how to add extra points to my data set in my 3D scatter plot:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  Plotly.extendTraces(my_Div, {
    x: [[Math.random()*100]],
    y: [[Math.random()*100]],
    z: [[Math.random()*100]]
  }, [0])

  // if (cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
}, 100);
```

However, I also want to have a dynamic *color* of the line to this point (which is possible when passing the points in one go). Thus, passing for example:

```
color: [[<some color>]]
```

However, this results in the error `cannot extend missing or non-array attribute: color`. Does anyone know how to do this? The documentation does not include a list of parameters that can be passed.

Answer (score 1):

Found it by fiddling around. I assume the initial data is added as follows:

```
var data = [{
    type: 'scatter3d',
    mode: 'lines',
    x: x,
    y: y,
    z: z,
    opacity: 1,
    line: {
      width: 10,
      color: c,
      reversescale: false
    }
  }];
```

Then one can extrend the color too;

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  Plotly.extendTraces(my_Div, {
    x: [[Math.random()*100]],
    y: [[Math.random()*100]],
    z: [[Math.random()*100]],
    'line.color': [[-1]]
  }, [0])

  // if (cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
}, 100);
```